# How to access array list in different class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I want to access **arraylist** which I have created in **BAL** class in class named **books**

BAL class

```
public class BAL {
 ArrayList<members> member=new ArrayList<members>();
       members m1=new members(1,"Tom", "12345678", "No");
       members m2=new members(2,"Richard", "23456789", "No");
       members m3=new members(3,"Hillary", "45678901", "The Wind in the Willows");
       public void member_add()
       {
       member.add(m1);
       member.add(m2);
       member.add(m3);
       }
       public ArrayList<members> ls()
       {
           return member;
       }
}
```

books class

```
public class books {
public static void member_stch()
    {
       BAL bl=new BAL();

        System.out.println(bl.ls().size()); 
    }
}
```

And main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        BAL strt=new BAL();

        strt.member_add();
        books.member_stch(); // result 0
        System.out.println(strt.ls().size()); // result 3

}
```

**I am getting 0 instead of 3 which is the size of Array List from books class**

I m getting the expected result if I access array list in main

Comment: make sure you post compiled code

Comment: I have placed simplified classes here  .. the compiled version has a lot of unrelated stuff..

Comment: Then, this question may not answer your question. There are lot of unresolved variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a second instance of BAL in your books class.  It is a different object than the one created in main.  You will need to pass either the BAL object from main into books, or its array list element, as a parameter to books.member_stch()

change like so in main:

```
books.member_stch();
```

to:

```
books.member_stch(strt);
```

and change member_stch from:

```
public static void member_stch()
{
   BAL bl=new BAL();

    System.out.println(bl.ls().size()); 
}
```

to:

```
public static void member_stch(BAL bl)
{
   System.out.println(bl.ls().size()); 
}
```

If you want to decouple BAL and books so that books does not need to know what a BAL is, you can replace

```
books.member_stch(strt);
```

with:

```
books.member_stch(strt.ls);
```

and:

```
public static void member_stch(BAL bl)
{
   System.out.println(bl.ls().size()); 
}
```

with:

```
public static void member_stch(ArrayList<Members> memberList)
{
   System.out.println(memberList.size()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `BAL` instance you create in main invokes `member_add()` - and this adds those three instances you expect.

The `BAL` instance you create in `member_stch()` of the book class does **not** do this.  It's not the same instance, and hence it's empty.  It's unclear what the intention of the code is, but if you'd like those 3 member instances added to every `BAL` instance you create, consider invoking the `add_member` method in the constructor of BAL.